# Issue with PHP Like query

Tags: php

I have a `PHP` error I cannot seem to fix with this code

```
$_POST['location'] = 'Northern Province';
$_POST['transport'] = 'transport';

if (isset($_POST['location'])) {
    $region = "%{$_POST['region']}%";
    $transport = "%{$_POST['transport']}%";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT users.id, users.email, users.profilePhoto, users.userType, organization.userFk, organization.name, organization.specialization from users, organization WHERE users.id = organization.userFk AND organization.specialization LIKE ? AND users.region LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $transport, $regions);
    $stmt->execute();
    $response["transPortCompanies"] = array();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $email, $profilePhoto, $userType, $userFk, $name, $specialization);

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $company = array();
        $company["id"] = $id;
        $company["email"] = $email;  
        $company["profilePhoto"] = $profilePhoto;
        $company["name"] = $name;
        $company["specialization"] = $specialization;
        $response["message"] = "Loaded";
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        array_push($response["transPortCompanies"], $company);
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Apparently it returns an empty `companies` list, but when I hardcode it like

```
SELECT users.id, users.email, users.profilePhoto, users.userType, organization.userFk, organization.name, organization.specialization from users, organization WHERE users.id = organization.userFk AND organization.specialization LIKE '%transport%' AND users.region LIKE '%Northern Province%'
```

I get my my output, so am wondering where am I going wrong? I have another script that does searching and that is how I implemented it

Comment: i have question with me. if there is no **relationship** between these two tables ? why not you use join them ?

Comment: @Karthi I plan on doing that, but for now I want the query to work, if it does them I plan on replacing it with a join

Comment: Having used error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have more than likely avoided this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have typo

```
bind_param("ss", $transport, $region); // "region", not "regionS"
```

Comment: @ThandiNgamu, this solution should work for you.

Comment: :D php isnt there an IDE that checks some of these things? thanks a lot that worked.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul thank you as  well for the effort, I couldnt have done it